# How to write to memory address?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, memory-address, read-write

New to pointers and unsafe world in C#. I was going through getting memory address of variables via pointers, move things around a bit here and there etc; basically learning.

```
static unsafe void M()
{
    var i = 1;
    var p = &i; //gets memory location of variable i here

    //how do I write to location p, say a value of 100?
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to write to a specific location as well? It helps a great deal to see what's going around if I can read and write at the same time.

No practical purposes, just learning. Or is it not possible with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer with the `*` operator. ex:

```
*p = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
*p = 100;

Console.WriteLine(i); // prints 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to deference it.

Here's a LINQPad snippet:

```
int i = 1;

unsafe
{
    var p = &i;

    *p = 100;
}

i.Dump();
```

This outputs "100", as expected.

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between your answer and this approach `Marshal.WriteInt32(new IntPtr(p), 100)`? Both works fine.

Comment: @nawfal, `Marshal` contains a whole host of methods for working with unmanaged memory and if you check the MSDN you'll notice that they're not marked as unsafe.